# SQL results - is it possible to display this layout on a .jar app (instead of tables)?

Tags: java

http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/990/jh1x.jpg

Good day everyone. I'm working with a project and I was wondering if it's possible for the results to appear like the image above instead of the image below on a .jar app?

The data is going to be pulled out on an SQL database. I just want to know if it's possible? It would be great if you could give me some tips. :)

http://img36.imageshack.us/img36/9683/7sxg.JPG

Answer (score 0):

Have you decided which library to use?  Swing or SWT should allow you a similar result by combining the diverse table, input and panel components.  Answering you question, I see that perfectly feasible with any of those options

Comment: Hmm. . I'm using Swing.

Comment: What I can't figure out is how to do it like this one: http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/990/jh1x.jpg

Should I put jLabels and stuff and just do setText() to display the search results? Guessing it's a bad idea. -_-

Comment: For example, you can make a prototype JPanel with your Search Result, and lay them down in a BoxLayout inside a JScrollPane.  I think that would be similar to what you need

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html if in doubt :)

Comment: I think I'm missing something. . But still, your link gave me an idea though :))

Comment: You can JTable ( with one/two columns, if you want to show person icon in different column) and you need to override Renderer to return new UI component that you display in each Cell. Implement this new UI component to show each Result how you wanted it to be. OR

Comment: . . I did it using jLabels though. . http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2443/rhwy.png

Comment: But not even close. . -_-
. . I've just learned how to program last 2 weeks, so "override renderer to return new UI component" feels something new. But still, thank you for the suggestion.